# If $m∠A = 50°$, side $a = 6$ units, and side $b = 10$ units, what is the maximum number of distinct triangles that can be constructed?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm stuck. Can I get a hint? I heard the answer is zero.

I'm guessing we use the SSA congruent triangle theorem.

If $m∠A = 50°$, side $a = 6$ units, and side $b = 10$ units, what is the maximum number of distinct triangles that can be constructed?

Comment: There is no SSA congruent triangle theorem.  Knowing two sides and an angle opposite one of them does not uniquely determine a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) states that 
$$\frac{a}{\sin\alpha} = \frac{b}{\sin\beta} = \frac{c}{\sin\gamma}$$
Therefore,
$$\sin\beta = \frac{b\sin\alpha}{a} = \frac{10\sin(50^\circ)}{6}$$
What do you know about the range of the sine function?

Comment: The range is [-1,1].

Comment: Good.  Now calculate the value of $\sin\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The rumors were true: there are no points common to  the ray and the circle.